# Unable to find textbox using White framework

Tags: c#, white-framework

I'm trying to set some value in the textbox (Automaion id:txtFieldID see attached image). I'm unable to get the elements inside this pane where the parent type looks like.

Winform
---> Win32
--------> InternetExplorer

Inside I have this textbox.

```
Application app = TestStack.White.Application.Attach("Encompass");
mainWindow = app.GetWindows();
TextBox txtFieldId = mainWindow.Get(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("TxtFieldID"));
```

On the last line I'm getting failed to textbox error.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjsXb.png) from inspect, please let me know how to set/get value in the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

The Get method from the `mainWindow` is using [TreeScope.Children](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.treescope(v=vs.110).aspx) at the lowest levels of White. This means you need to find elements along the way to get to the element you want to set the text on. This is a good practice with UIA to find all the elements along the way instead of searching from the top level of the application. If you search from the top level of your application you could end up traversing many elements and it can take a very long time to complete. This particularly gets painful when you have tables and grids which can have three or more controls inside each cell.

Here is some example code which may or may not work exactly as is. I had to do this only based off of the screen shot. Also the screenshot of inspect is very helpful for questions like this so good job on posting that. I wish everyone would post screen shots of inspect with their UIA problems.

```
        Application app = TestStack.White.Application.Attach("Encompass");
        //If you have more than one window you will need to do something else here to get the right window.
        Window mainWindow = app.GetWindows().First();

        //Searching on the type without anything else should get the first element it finds of that type.
        //I highly suggest looking at the elements and see if you can find anything else unique about them to search on.
        Panel panel1 = mainWindow.Get<Panel>();
        Panel panel2 = panel1.Get<Panel>();
        Panel panel3 = panel2.Get<Panel>();
        Tab tab = panel3.Get<Tab>(); 
        //Text searches the name property in inspect.
        Panel loan = tab.Get<Panel>(SearchCriteria.ByText("Loan"));
        Window subWindow = loan.Get<Window>();
        Panel panel4 = subWindow.Get<Panel>();
        Panel panel5 = panel4.Get<Panel>();
        Panel panel6 = panel5.Get<Panel>();
        Panel panel7 = panel6.Get<Panel>();
        Panel panel8 = panel7.Get<Panel>();
        Panel panel9 = panel8.Get<Panel>();
        Panel panel10 = panel9.Get<Panel>();
        Panel panel11 = panel10.Get<Panel>();
        TextBox txtField = panel11.Get<TextBox>(SearchCriteria.ByAutomationId("TxtFieldID"));
        //Setting the text property will set the text in your text box.
        txtField.Text = "Your text here.";
```

I can't see all the properties of each element so I did this using what I can see in the TreeView which is LocalizedControlType and Name generally. I would highly recommend going back and changing my code to using AutomationId where ever possible in addition to the ControlType.